# Why is the restriction on newtype?

Tags: haskell

I read that "newtype has exactly one constructor with exactly one field inside it." Is this restriction adds any advantage? If the value constructor is limited with only one field, why can't i use the field directly in my code, instead of wrapping it with newtype?

Comment: Newtype gives you a way to distinguish from the prior type when there is semantic difference.  For example, `newtype Latittute = Lat Double ; newtype Longitude = Lon Double`.  You also get to define your classes all over again, fun!

Comment: Thanks, I can use type keyword for that right. Is there any additional advantage?

Comment: No, `type Latitude = Double` would not give you any type safety.  If you swap values of type `Double` or other type aliases for `Double` there is no compile time error.  `type _ = _ `  only creates an alias.

Comment: Ya got it. Is this the only advantage? I can go for data keyword by limiting to one value constructor and one filed, like "data Latitude = Lat Double"

Comment: Newtype is also strict, so your semantics regarding bottom are different and performance can differ too.

Comment: if you want to read a bit more about this you can check out [newtype](https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype) on the Haskell-wiki

Comment: @HariKrishna However `data` will actually *consume memory*. A `newtype` will be completely erased when compiling (which also yield strictness as Thomas mentions) so you have absolutely 0 overhead for using a `newtype` in both space and time. It is just a tool to distinguish types for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`newtype` is a tool for creating data abstraction that has no runtime cost.

## What do I mean by abstraction?

Suppose you have:

```
greetPerson :: String -> String -> String
greetPerson greeting name = greeting ++ " " ++ name

greetPerson "Hello" "Mike" => "Hello Mike"
```

This works fine, but it opens opportunities for misuse:

```
greetPerson "Mike" "Hello" => "Mike Hello"
```

The problem is that you're using the same type everywhere (`String`), carrying no semantic meaning. Let's use a newtype:

```
newtype Name = Name String

greetPerson :: String -> Name -> String
greetPerson greeting (Name name) = greeting ++ " " ++ name

greetPerson "Hello" (Name "Mike") => "Hello Mike"
```

We end up with the same functionality, but now the type signature carries more meaning and the compiler can tell us when we misuse it.

## What do I mean by no runtime cost?

The `newtype` from my example exists only at the type level and the compiler generates exactly the same code as if I used `String` throughout.

This hints at why `newtype` is only allowed for one constructor with one field.

Imagine you tried to make `newtype` work for more than one constructor. How would you distinguish which one you have at runtime? You'd have to store some additional information.

Same with more than one field. You'd need some way to bundle two fields together.

All of them add some runtime cost which `newtype` promises not to do.

If you want more than one field or more than one constructor simply use `data`:

```
data Foo = Bar String | Baz Int Bool
```